# Determine which year-month has the highest and lowest value

Tags: sql, oracle, top-n

Here's my first query to shows the number of customers added per year-month

```
select count(name) AS CUSTOMER, 
       extract(year from create_date) as yr, 
       extract(month from create_date) as mon
from x
group by extract(year from create_date), 
         extract(month from create_date)
order by yr desc, mon desc;
```

| CUSTOMER | YR | MON |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2019 | 07 |
| 4 | 2015 | 02 |
| 100 | 2014 | 09 |
| 3 | 2014 | 04 |

I tried the query

```
SELECT MAX(count(*))
FROM x
GROUP BY create_date;
```

in the results I have;

| MAX(COUNT(*)) |
| --- |
| 100 |

need to see the year and month in the result.

How to do this?

Comment: Your question has several format problems, but, ignoring that, have you tried parsing to number the year and month of the date? `to_number(to_char(create_date, 'YYYYMM'))`.

Answer (score 1):

The way I understood the question, you'd use `rank` analytic function in a subquery (or a CTE) and fetch rows whose count is either minimum or maximum. Something like this:

```
with temp as
  (select to_char(create_date, 'yyyymm') yyyy_mm,
          count(*) cnt,
          --
          rank() over (order by count(*)  asc) rnk_min,
          rank() over (order by count(*) desc) rnk_max
   from x
   group by to_char(create_date, 'yyyymm')
  )
select yyyy_mm,
       cnt
from temp
where rnk_min = 1
   or rnk_max = 1;
```

Comment: "cnt" : invalid indentifier

Comment: Not any more; forgot to set alias (line #3). Fixed; sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two levels of aggregation and put the results all in one row using `keep` (which implements a "first" aggregation function):

```
select max(num_customers) as max_num_customers,
       max(yyyymm) keep (dense_rank first order by num_customers desc) as max_yyyymm,
       min(num_customers) as max_num_customers,
       max(yyyymm) keep (dense_rank first order by num_customers asc) as in_yyyymm,
from (select to_char(create_date, 'YYYY-MM') as yyyymm,
             count(*) AS num_customers
      from x
      group by to_char(create_date, 'YYYY-MM'
     ) ym
```

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle 12, you can use `FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY` to get the row with the highest number of customers (and, in the case of ties, the latest date):

```sql
SELECT count(name) AS CUSTOMER,
       extract(year from create_date) as yr, 
       extract(month from create_date) as mon
FROM   x
GROUP BY
       extract(year from create_date), 
       extract(month from create_date)
ORDER BY
       customer DESC,
       yr DESC,
       mon DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;
```

If you want to include ties for the highest number of customers then:

```sql
SELECT count(name) AS CUSTOMER,
       extract(year from create_date) as yr, 
       extract(month from create_date) as mon
FROM   x
GROUP BY
       extract(year from create_date), 
       extract(month from create_date)
ORDER BY
       customer DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES;
```